# How to change port to run polymer projects?

Tags: polymer

When I try to run `polymer serve` on terminal, it always run with port 8080. But it collapse with another services I've configured with that port. How can I change the default port to run the projects, for example, in port 8081?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an option for that:

`polymer serve --port 8081`

Comment: Where would you set this flag as the new default in a project repo?

Comment: @ScottRomack I don't know from the top of my head. Maybe you could ask a new question and someone else could help you? This comment probably won't attract much attention.